# CKAN h.url_is_local(res.url) not working as expected

Tags: jinja2, ckan

I'm trying to define how urls are presented in the package: resource_read.html

If an url is external, meaning the url points to a resource not in the datastore, or filestore, the url presented will be created like this:

```
<a href="{{h.full_current_url()}}/download"title="{{h.full_current_url()}}/download">
```

and shows something like: http://ckan.example.com/dataset/trafic/resource/c0942853-e96e-4bc6-884c-462af7758e75/download

This works fine. But if the file was uploaded to the fileStore the url is local, and this breaks as the logic will look something like this: http://ckan.example.com/dataset/trafic/resource/a2189f9d-b4e8-4059-b87f-8fa12c865775/download/python-examples.zip

hence doing just the /download/ is not sufficient.

I tried using the helper method h.url_is_local(res.url) but it does not work as expected, can't get it to return anything other than "".

If anyone has any help or can link me to an example of how to do this properly i would appreaciate it.